# Unity VR World Space Canvas UI and objects overlapping

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem in my VR application.
I made something like a menu in a canvas (world-space canvas) and I attached it to the main camera (the only one I need).

[image]

The problem is that the menu (the canvas) which is about 1 meter ahead of the main camera is crashing with the rest of elements of the scene (walls, etc.), when these walls/other elements are closer than menu to the camera.

I'm trying to find out a way to assign some kind of precedence to the canvas menu to avoid the overlapping and show the whole menu always.

Comment: Just create a new camera only for the UI rendering purpose. Then attach all of the UI to that camera and render that image on top of the other/main camera with opaque background.

Comment: Or stop using a world space canvas. If it's attached to the camera, you may as well use a screen space or overlay canvas.